# Custom foreign key column name

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm trying to connect a lagacy database and I'm having some troubles. I'm using Grails 3.2.3 and Postgresql 9.4. When a try to change the column name, GORM create the column twice, one time with the name i choose and the other with GORM column name format.
The column is **estado** in **Cidade** entity and I need to map it to **"EstadoId"**.

It creating both:
"EstadoId" integer NOT NULL
 estadoid integer NOT NULL,

```
class Cidade {
  int id
  String nome
  Boolean capital

  static mapping = {
    table '`tbCidades`'
    id column: '`CidadeId`'
    nome column: '`Nome`'
    capital column: '`Capital`'
    estado column:  '`EstadoId`'
    version false
  }

  static belongsTo = [ estado : Estado]
}
```

```
class Estado {
  int id
  String sigla

  static hasMany = [ cidades: Cidade ]

  static mapping = {
    table '`tbEstados`'
    id column: '`EstadoId`'
    sigla column: '`Sigla`'
    version false
  }
}
```

I noticed with I choose a name using underscore format (Like: **my_column_estado** it works.)

Answer (score 0):

It's default bahaviour of grails; when you use

`static belongsTo = [ estado : Estado]`

it's creating `estado_id` column which is mapping to `estado` instance. Have you try to remove constraint:

`estado column:  '`EstadoId`'`

drop test db and recompile project?

Comment: Actually I need the column to has the name "EstadoId". But since a didn't need any cascade a just declared the atribute like this:  Estado estado and mapped the column name :estado column: "EstadoId".